# PythonでWindowsのショートカットを作成したい

Tags: python, python3, windows

PythonでWindowsのショートカットを作成することはできるのでしょうか。
windows 10 Pro, Python3.7です。

`C:\Users\username\Desktop\` に `C:\Users\username\Downloads\` へのショートカットを作成したいと考えていますが、検索しても調べ方が悪いのかそれらしいものが引っかかりません。

.batでも.vbsをかませる必要があり、ショートカット作成は難しいものなのかと思っております。

詳しい方、よろしくお願いいたします。

**追記**
saitokさんの回答だと、python3で`pip install mklnk`でインストールできなかったのですが、ご本人に別質問で補足を頂き、解決したので貼っておきます。
[pipでmklnkがインストールできない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69699/pip%E3%81%A7mklnk%E3%81%8C%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

Comment: この辺の記事があるようです。試してみてください。[create a shortcut(.lnk) of file in windows with python3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60943757/9014308), [Building a Windows Shortcut with Python](https://pbpython.com/windows-shortcut.html), [ContinuumIO/menuinst](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/menuinst)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ライブラリを使ってよいのであれば、[mklnk](https://github.com/blacklanternsecurity/mklnk)が使えそうです（Win10で試して、作成できました）。内部的には[pylnk](https://github.com/strayge/pylnk)([pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pylnk/))を使っているようです。

```py
import mklnk

mklnk.create_lnk('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Downloads.lnk',
                 target='C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads',
                 mode='Normal',
                 args='',
                 description='',
                 icon='',
                 workingDir='',
                 is_dir=True)
```

Comment: pip install mklnkでインストールできません。。。なぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

mklnkが利用できないとのことで、comtypesでWSHを呼び出す方法で作ってみました。

```
pip install comtypes
```

で、あらかじめライブラリをインストールしておいてください。
あまりきれいではないですが、ショートカットを作成するサンプルを作ってみました。
ソースコード内にもコメントで書いていますが、ショートカット作成時に指定したい情報がある場合は、適宜コメントを解除して指定してください。

```
import comtypes.client
import os

#リンク先のファイル名
target_file=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "test.exe")
#ショートカットを作成するパス
save_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"test.lnk")
#WSHを生成
wsh=comtypes.client.CreateObject("wScript.Shell",dynamic=True)
#ショートカットの作成先を指定して、ショートカットファイルを開く。作成先のファイルが存在しない場合は、自動作成される。
short=wsh.CreateShortcut(save_path)
#以下、ショートカットにリンク先やコメントといった情報を指定する。
#リンク先を指定
short.TargetPath=target_file
#コメントを指定する
short.Description="テストショートカット"
#引数を指定したい場合は、下記のコメントを解除して、引数を指定する。
#short.arguments="/param1"
#アイコンを指定したい場合は、下記のコメントを解除してアイコンのパスを指定する。
#short.IconLocation="C:\\test\\test.ico"
#作業ディレクトリを指定したい場合は、下記のコメントを解除してディレクトリのパスを指定する。
#short.workingDirectory="c:\\test\\"
#ショートカットファイルを作成する
short.Save()
```

以上、参考になれば幸いです。