# pipでmklnkがインストールできない

Tags: python, pip

以下質問
[PythonでWindowsのショートカットを作成したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69212/python%e3%81%a7windows%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88%e3%82%ab%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e4%bd%9c%e6%88%90%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

でmklnkで実現可能とのことですが、`pip install mklnk`でインストールできません。
（ググりましたが、mklnkのページはほとんど出現しませんでした。）

```
pip install mklnk
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mklnk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mklnk
```

となっています。pipだとインストールできない、ということでよろしいのでしょうか？
その場合、どのように実行するのでしょうか。
わかる方、よろしくお願いいたします。

**実行環境**
Windows 10
Python 3.7

Comment: 元々 "インストール" に関する質問だったはずですから、回答を受けて湧いた新たな疑問 (UNCパスの話) は、新しい別の質問として投稿すべきだと思います。/ 参考: [質問の回答を受けて別の質問を追加したい時はどうしたら良い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3345)

Comment: 承知いたしました。移行いたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

前回解答しました。`mklnk`はそもそもpipに存在しないので、とりあえず手動で実行するディレクトリに置けばよいと思います。また、 https://github.com/strayge/pylnk は python3 に対応しています。実際、私もpython3で動作を確認しています。次のようなディレクトリ構造にして`main.py`を実行しました。

- `working_directory/`

  - `pylnk.py` # https://github.com/strayge/pylnk/blob/master/pylnk3.py から取得
  - `mklnk.py` # https://github.com/blacklanternsecurity/mklnk/blob/master/lnk.py から取得
  - `main.py` # 前回の解答で書いたサンプルコード

Comment: 無事、ショートカット作成できました。ありがとうございます。元記事にもリンク貼っておきます。

Comment: すいません。もう一点質問なのですが、UNCパスには対応していないのでしょうか？
mklnk()を走らせるとCドライブのパスを指定すると普通に走るのですが、UNCパスだとエラーが出ました。

Answer (score 3):

前回の質問の回答で紹介されている [mklnk](https://github.com/blacklanternsecurity/mklnk) の README を見ると、対応しているのは Python 2.x のみのようです (Python 3.x は未対応)。

> Requires Python 2 (pylnk does not support python 3)