# mklnkでショートカットを作成する際のUNCパスへの対応

Tags: python

**実行環境**
Windows 10
Python 3.7

[pipでmklnkがインストールできない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69699/pip%e3%81%a7mklnk%e3%81%8c%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

に関連した質問ですが、UNCパスを指定したからか、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

UNCパスには非対応なのでしょうか？また、これを回避する方法はありますでしょうか？
（mklnkでなくてもPythonであれば構いません。）

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "\\hoge\mklnk.py", line 52, in create_lnk
    elements = [pylnk.RootEntry(pylnk.ROOT_MY_COMPUTER), pylnk.DriveEntry(target_drive)]
  File "\\hoge\pylnk.py", line 493, in __init__
    raise FormatException("This is not a valid drive: " + str(drive))
pylnk.FormatException: This is not a valid drive:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNCパスを指定するためには[`pylink3.py`に`ROOT_NETWORK_PLACES`を渡す](https://github.com/strayge/pylnk/blob/7daeb5417e9ebb471005c1fe814e6c0ed75110c5/pylnk3.py#L856-L867)必要がありますが、[`link.py`は`ROOT_MY_COMPUTER`を決めうちで渡して](https://github.com/blacklanternsecurity/mklnk/blob/9bd41d484f3f2d2cf4041e128c36a20a8407dad3/lnk.py#L58)います。この組み合わせではUNCパスは使用できないということになります。

[user29034さんの提案されているcomtypesを使用する方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/69707/4236)が安定しているのかもしれません。